# Is it possible to make a horizontal line using a report module?

Tags: commcare

I have a report module that shows a basic bar graph, is there a way to configure an additional line at say `y=15`?

The output I'm attempting to achieve is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to "hack" this to work. One way to do it, is to use the `y-labels` and `y-max` setting.

Under chart configuration, add a box for `y-labels` and set the value to wherever you want your line to be. For example `'{ "10": "Goal" }'` would create a line at `y=10` and label with Goal.

The next trick to this is to set your `y-max` value under Chart Configuration to something that is greater than or equal to your horizontal line. This way you are guaranteed your horizontal line will show.

[image]

Documentation [here](https://github.com/dimagi/commcare-core/wiki/Graphs#configuration-series)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible in a report module. I believe you would need to use a manual graphing configuration off of the underlying report fixture data to achieve this.

Comment: Confirming, that's true.